# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC Session looses the value

Tags: session, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app. I have a method in the controller that set a value in session.

When I call another the same method, the `Session` is empty.

When I call the method for the fourth time, then the value is kept. I do not know if is there a delay or what.

Here is my controller:

```
 private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
 private readonly ISessionHelpers _sessionHelpers;

 public CobraController(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, ISessionHelpers sessionHelpers)
 {
     _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
     _sessionHelpers = sessionHelpers;
 }
```

This is the method:

```
[HttpPost("LandingPage")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ClientWebError(IsPartial = true)]
public async Task<IActionResult> LandingPage()
{
    return PartialView("Landing", await GetEmployeeCounts());
}

private async Task<string> GetEmployeeCounts()
{
    if (_contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session == null)
        throw new Exception(ConstantValues.SESSIONNULLERROR);
   
    var session = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
    string employeeCount = _sessionHelpers.GetString(session, ConstantValues.SESSIONEMPLOYEECOUNT);
    _sessionHelpers.SetString(session, ConstantValues.SESSIONEMPLOYEECOUNT, "VALUE");
    return employeeCount;
}
```

In `program.cs` I have this

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
});
```

The session called `ConstantValues.SESSIONEMPLOYEECOUNT` only keeps the value after I call the method several times...

If I want to read `Session` set in other controllers, I have a problem reading it.

I think is a problem with Visual Studio 2023 because when I deploy it in the server, it works fine

What could be happening?

Thanks

Comment: I was wrong, i am using NET Core 6 MVC. thanks

Comment: I suggest you could check your browser's cookie to make sure it store the right session id and test with other browser.